# How to use SharedElement which works in viewPager fragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment, transition

I'm having only 1 activity. Firstly, it displays fragment1, inside that fragment, i have a recyclerView to display a list of cardviews, inside each CardView, there is an image. When user tap on each CardView, fragment1 will be replaced by the fragment 2. Fragment2 contains a viewPager, viewpager display the same data with recyclerView in fragment1 but more specific. I want to make a shareElement animation between image1 in fragment1 to image2 in fragment2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you begin transaction you can add shared element transition like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .addSharedElement(sharedElement, transitionName)
    .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

and give same transition name in xml of other fragment

```
android:transitionName="transitionName"
```